# Can enums have variable number of parameters?

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to implement an enum like this:

```
public enum Colors{
     REDISH ("red", "crimson", "pink")
     BLUEISH ("blue", "oceanic", "sky", "darkblue", "lightblue")
     YELLOWISH ("yellow", "orange")
     ...

     private List<String> values;
}
```

The above code obviously doesn't work, but I couldn't find any info about how to implement it.

Can this be done somehow? And if not, what would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can just add a constructor with a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) parameter:

```
public enum Colors{
     REDISH ("red", "crimson", "pink"),
     BLUEISH ("blue", "oceanic", "sky", "darkblue", "lightblue"),
     YELLOWISH ("yellow", "orange");

     private List<String> values;

     Colors(String ...strings){
         values = Arrays.asList(strings);
     }
}
```